# Not sure if this function is right to calculate what I need

Tags: python

So what I want the code to do is collect grades as 1,2, or 3 if one of these numbers isn't chosen then redirect the person to input again until the correct answer is input then continue to run the rest of the code.
The program should process an undetermined number of persons

```
for g_rade in grade:`
  if grade != '1' or '2' or '3':`
    print("Please enter the correct grade")`
continue`
  if grade == '1'or '2' or '3':`
break`
  if grade ==1:`
     if overall grade <= 70:`
        addded_grade = grade + 3`
        print(addded_grade)`
  elif grade > 75 and grade < 80:`
        addded_grade = grade + 5`
        print(addded_grade)
  else: 
        addded_grade= grade + 4`
        print(addded_grade)`
 if grade == 2:`
      if grade < 50:`
         addded_grade= grade + 2`
          print(addded_grade)`
      else:`
          addded_grade = grade + 1`
          print(addded_grade )`
 if grade == 3:`
          addded_grade= grade + 0.5`
          print(addded_grade)`
 print("Finished")`
```

Comment: Please format your code properly so that the indentation is easily understood, enclose your entire code within triple backticks(``` ```)

Comment: Use a while loop and use `continue` to return back to the input.

Comment: your code is so messed up and you didn't tell when to finish. 
how the program should know if your unknown number of persons is over?
and what exactly you want to be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with the problem at hand, you basically want to continuously ask for input until it is valid. This can be achieved with a simple `while` loop.
Sample code:

```
valid = ['1', '2', '3']
a = input('Enter a Grade')
while a not in valid:
    a = input('Enter a valid Grade')
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter a Grade
5
Enter a valid Grade
6
Enter a valid Grade
9
Enter a valid Grade
2
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if grade != '1' or '2' or '3':
```

Is almost certainly wrong. It parses as:

```
if (grade != '1') or '2' or '3':
```

As `'2'` and `'3'` are always true, this entire conditional is *always* true.

If you want to determine if `grade` is one of those values, you can use `in` to check if it exists in a set.

```
if grade in {'1', '2', '3'}:
```